# Inconsistent tags: .bash-profile (with dot) vs bashrc (no dot)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-request

#### Problem

There is the tag [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile), note the leading dot. Currently it has no synonyms, so the "canonical" tag is naturally *with the dot*. And there is also [bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) with [.bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) as its synonym, but the "canonical" tag is the one *without a dot*.

**For consistency** I'd like the "canonical" tags to be either *both with dots* or *both without dots*. The other forms can be synonyms then.

---

#### Research

Pro dots in "canonical" tags:

- The files used by Bash are named `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, with dots.

Against dots in "canonical" tags:

- My list of watched tags contains [`bash*`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash*) and this covers many tags related to pure Bash, including [bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bashrc), but not [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile). I have added [`.bash*`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash*) to the list and currently this entry covers only [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile). The fact `.bash*` does not match [.bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) makes me believe that only the "canonical" tags count. So if we make the tags with dots "canonical" then I will still need `bash*` and `.bash*` (I know I can use [`*bash*`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/*bash*), but suppose I don't want [git-bash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/git-bash) to match). But if we create [bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash-profile) and make the tags without dots "canonical" then `bash*` will be enough to cover all the tags related to pure Bash. **Quite elegant.**

I note ([here](https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms)) that [.bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) as a synonym of [bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) is not particularly useful. It has been renamed to [bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) 11 times, while the total number of questions tagged [bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) is 289. [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile) works well without any synonym and [bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash-profile) does not exist (yet). So *maybe* we don't really need synonyms for these tags in the first place.

[image]

OTOH when one creates a question (or browses tags [here](https://superuser.com/tags)) and types `bash-profile`, the site suggests [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile); but e.g. for `.linux` it does not suggest [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux). Therefore I conclude that:

- [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile) and [.bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) probably can work reasonably well without synonyms (the right tag will be suggested even if a user types without the dot), so if we opt for "canonical" tags with dots then *maybe* we won't need the tags without dots as synonyms; the fact [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile) works well without [bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash-profile) supports this;
- but [bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash-profile) and [bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) probably cannot work reasonably well without synonyms (the right tag won't be suggested if a user types with the dot), so if we opt for "canonical" tags without dots then we should keep the tags with dots as synonyms.

---

#### My preference

Personally I'm against dots in "canonical" tags. I would like [bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash-profile) and [bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) to be "canonical" (the former would have to be created), [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile) and [.bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) to be respective synonyms. But even if we decide the "canonical" tags should be both with dots, it will still be more consistent than the current situation.

---

#### How other sites do it

- On [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) `bash-profile` and `bashrc` are synonyms for `bash`; `.bash-profile` and `.bashrc` do not exist. `.bash-logout` is standalone (it's not a synonym for `bash`) but `bash-logout` does not exist.
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) has `bashrc`, no `.bashrc`. `.bash-history` is a synonym for `bash`, but there is no `bash-history`.
- On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) `.bash-profile`, `.bashrc` and `bashrc` are synonyms for `bash`; `bash-profile` does not exist though.

It seems none of these sites has managed to create (or maintain) a fully consistent policy regarding these tags. So maybe inconsistencies are not that bad; maybe the inconsistency I'm asking about is not that bad; *maybe* we should just let our tags be.

---

#### Questions

1. **Should we remove the inconsistency between [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile) (dot) and [bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) (no dot)?**
2. If so, which form (with or without a dot) should be "canonical" for both tags?
3. Do we need synonyms for them? For both of them?

Comment: I could have sworn I'd commented here before, but apparently not, so... my two cents. I think we should remove the inconsistency, that the "with a dot" form should be canonical, and that bash-profile and bashrc should be synonyms for .bash-profile and .bashrc respectively, regardless of what the other sites do.